# Getting “code”:400 in k6, however the postman is able to run successfully

Tags: performance, load-testing, k6

Below is the example of my postman equivalent curl

```
 curl --location 'http://my-service/v3/legacy/import?family=WGeneric' \
--header 'X-TRS-AUTH-PERMS: {{auth_perms}}' \
--header 'X-Trs-Auth-Alias: {{auth_alias}}' \
--header 'X-APIKEY: <qwertyuiopasdfghjkl;>' \
--form 'file=@"/Users/xx/load-test/scripts/files/data.xls"'
```

output:

```
{
    "msg": "File successfully uploaded and submitted to avdownload",
    "sha256": "sdfghjksdfgh5678dhkhfkdsfdsfdsf",
    "success": true
}
```

Below is my k6 code, (I have put only the relevant part)

```
const filePath = '/Users/xx/load-test/scripts/files/data.xls';

// Read the file content during the initialization phase
const fileContent = open(filePath);
if (!fileContent) {
    console.error(`Error reading file content from ${filePath}`);
    // Abort the test or handle the error as needed
}

export default function () {
    const apikey = __ENV.API_KEY;

    const headers = {
        'X-APIKEY': apikey,
    };

    const response = http.request( "POST", baseURL, fileContent, {
        headers: headers,
    });

    check(response, {
        'status is 200': (r) => r.status === 200,
    });
    console.log(`Request URL: ${baseURL}`);
    console.log(`Request Headers: ${JSON.stringify(headers)}`);
    console.log(`Response Status Code: ${response.status}`);
    console.log(`Response Body: ${response.body}`);
    sleep(1);
}
```

the output of logs would be

```
INFO[0027] Response Status Code: 400                     source=console
INFO[0027] Response Body: {"@status":"error","code":400.......}
```

Wanted to know,

1. Am I passing the file details right.>? ( i am planning to run this on multiple files )
2. Is there any formating needed at the nginx side in k8s?